# I want to share my recylerview's item's text on social media apps with share button from adapter

Tags: android-recyclerview, share, parcelable

I tried several ways but failed. the last try is giving me this error.

error: incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,myList);

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExampleViewHolder holder, final int i) {
    ListQuotes currentItem = exampleList.get(i);
    holder.textView1.setText(currentItem.getArabicText());
    holder.textView2.setText(currentItem.getEnglishText());
    holder.numbering.setText(String.valueOf(i+1));

    holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
            myList.add(exampleList.get(i).getArabicText()); // Add your image URIs here
            myList.add(exampleList.get(i).getEnglishText());

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,myList);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null));

        }
    });

    }
```